# Where to find debug messages in Windows RT app?

Tags: windows-runtime

I'm new to Win RT development and I'm currently developing a windows RT app in which I've sent a debug build of my app to the tester. I'm wondering where can I find the output of the debug messages? Would it be possible to redirect the debug output to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use the system.diagnostics.debug to output the debug info.

In the desktop version .NET, you can add the Debug.Listeners to catch the log and output to file. But in the .NET for Store App, you can not add file listener.

The alternative way to log is using ETW (Event Tracing for Windows).

Code Sample: [Logging Sample for Windows Store Apps (ETW Logging in WinRT)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Logging-Sample-for-Windows-0b9dffd7/sourcecode?fileId=67472&pathId=1209661119)

The blog [HOW TO WRITE LOG FILES IN WINDOWS STORE APPS](https://bernhardelbl.wordpress.com/2013/01/12/how-to-write-log-files-in-windows-store-apps/) also introduced several ways to log in Windows Store App.